# Fortran Function Polymorphism

Tags: function, fortran, polymorphism

Can one have a function whose result is an unlimited polymorphic variable? I would like to be able to output either a number or a string from the function. However, the string is to be a one dimentional array.

Putting the following will work for the string, but introduces problems when trying a scalar number.

```
Class (*), Dimension (:) :: t
```

Comment: Is this substantially different from your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/q/26951750/3157076?

Comment: I forgot about that one. Thanks. Although there ase a feq complications of wnat compiles or not. I am trying things out on a timing function.

Comment: However I want to output an array.

Comment: My mistake, will update the question.

Comment: Forget it.  Procedure calls will seek to match argument rank, type and kind.  `class(*)` will take care of type and kind, but you ain't going to match on rank on a scalar and on an array.  OTOH for many Fortran programmers a string is a character variable with a length greater than one, not an array of characters.  Why don't you code that up, see how you get on.

Comment: I removed dimension and things workin as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I thing this is such an example:

```
  select type (x=>f())
    type is (integer)
      print *,x
  end select

contains

  function f()
    class(*), allocatable :: f
    allocate(f, source=10)
  end function

end
```

Unfortunately, both my compilers (gfortran 4.10, ifort 14) crash on this.