# How are function interfaces specified in abstract interface blocks for deferred binding as a type bound procedure?

Tags: fortran

I want to declare an abstract type `abstract_tensor` and specify some procedures (including their interfaces) that every type extending `abstract_tensor` must implement.

As an example, let's say I want every type extending `abstract_tensor` to have a type bound procedure `sph` that returns an instance of the concrete type and is a *function*, not a subroutine.

Here's a non-compiling implementation of that situation:

```
module tensors

  implicit none

  private
  public :: sym_tensor

  type, abstract :: abstract_tensor
   contains
     procedure(tr_interface), deferred :: tr
     procedure(sph_interface), deferred :: sph
  end type abstract_tensor

  abstract interface
     !! intrinsic return type works
     function tr_interface(self)
       import :: abstract_tensor
       class(abstract_tensor), intent(in) :: self
       real :: tr_interface
     end function tr_interface
     !! abstract return type not - how do I define the return type correctly here?
     function sph_interface(self)
       import :: abstract_tensor
       class(abstract_tensor), intent(in) :: self
       class(abstract_tensor) :: sph_interface
     end function sph_interface
  end interface

  type, extends(abstract_tensor) :: sym_tensor
     real :: xx = 0.0
     real :: yy = 0.0
     real :: zz = 0.0
     real :: xy = 0.0
     real :: yz = 0.0
     real :: xz = 0.0
   contains
     procedure :: tr => trace
     procedure :: sph => spherical_part
  end type sym_tensor

contains

  real function trace(self)
    class(sym_tensor), intent(in) :: self
    trace = self%xx + self%yy + self%zz
  end function trace

  type(sym_tensor) function spherical_part(self)
    class(sym_tensor), intent(in) :: self
    real :: tr
    tr = 1.0/3.0*self%tr()
    spherical_part = sym_tensor(tr, tr, tr, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
  end function spherical_part

end module tensors

program main

  use tensors, only: sym_tensor

  implicit none

  type(sym_tensor) :: t

end program main
```

Here, `sym_tensor` extends `abstract_tensor` and the type bound procedures `tr` and `sph` compute it's trace and hydrostatic part. The return type of the `tr` should be `real`, the return type of `sph` should be another `sym_tensor`.

How can I define the return type of `sph_interface` in the `abstract interface` block so that this compiles and forces every type extending the abstract type to implement such a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Fortran, all abstract polymorphic variables [must be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26952438/8559300) one of:

- dummy variables
- pointers
- allocatables

Your abstract function

```
function sph_interface(self)
  import :: abstract_tensor
  class(abstract_tensor), intent(in) :: self
  class(abstract_tensor) :: sph_interface
end function sph_interface
```

returns a variable of `class(abstract_tensor)`, which is an abstract polymorphic variable but not one of the above.

The easiest change is to make the return type `allocatable`:

```
function sph_interface(self)
  import :: abstract_tensor
  class(abstract_tensor), intent(in) :: self
  class(abstract_tensor), allocatable :: sph_interface
end function sph_interface
```

And then the `sym_tensor` implementation needs to have a matching signature:

```
function spherical_part(self)
  class(sym_tensor), intent(in) :: self
  class(abstract_tensor), allocatable :: spherical_part
  real :: tr
  tr = 1.0/3.0*self%tr()
  spherical_part = sym_tensor(tr, tr, tr, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
end function spherical_part
```

This will compile, but may well cause a segfault, because the compiler doesn't like the polymorphic assignment

```
spherical_part = sym_tensor(tr, tr, tr, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

you can solve this by replacing the simple assignment with a sourced allocation,

```
allocate(spherical_part, source=sym_tensor(tr, tr, tr, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

I am unsure if the sourced allocation is needed due to a limitation of the Fortran standard or a limitation of the compiler.

Comment: Thank you! Just two questions concering this allocation workaround: The allocation `allocate(spherical_part, source=sym_tensor(tr, tr, tr, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))` will automatically concretize the type of `spherical_part` from `abstract_tensor` to `sym_tensor` *at runtime*, right? Doesn't this RTTI have performance implications?

Comment: And furthermore, concerning the last sentence of the answer, what exactly is meant with "this"? Is the restriction of abstract polymorphic variables to the three use cases you described part of the standard?

Comment: I've updated my last sentence to be more specific. Is that clearer? And yes, the allocate will automatically concretize the type. Also, yes, this is runtime polymorphism and will have performance implications. Fortran doesn't have compile-time polymorphism.